# Java object locks equals or synchronized equals? (valid for hashcode as well)

Tags: java, multithreading, equals, hashcode

What is the recommended way to synchronize during a call to the equals method, is it overriding equals and adding the keyword `synchronized` or is it better to acquire a lock on both objects when calling equals?

For instance, I have:

```
public class EqualsTesterHelper {

    public int test = 0;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (!(obj instanceof EqualsTesterHelper)){
            return false;
        }
        EqualsTesterHelper a = (EqualsTesterHelper) obj;
        return (a.test == this.test);
    }   
}
```

Now if I use multiple threads testing the equals method, it obviously fails, using for instance:

```
public class EqualsTesterMain{
    private static EqualsTesterHelper helper1 = new EqualsTesterHelper();
    private static EqualsTesterHelper helper2 = new EqualsTesterHelper();
    private static Random rand = new Random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        helper1.test = 1;
        helper2.test = 1;
        System.out.println(helper1.equals(helper2));
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            executor.execute(new RunnerTest());
        }

    }

    private static class RunnerTest implements Runnable{

        public void run() {
            while (true){
                modifyHelper(helper1, rand.nextInt(10)); 
                helper1.equals(helper2);
                modifyHelper(helper2, rand.nextInt(10));
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        private void modifyHelper(EqualsTesterHelper helper, int newValue){
            helper.test = newValue;
        }   
    }
}
```

I obviously get inconsistent result due to data racing.

So would it be better that I modify *EqualsTesterHelper* equals method to :

```
@Override
public  synchronized boolean equals(Object obj) {
    synchronized(obj){
        if (!(obj instanceof EqualsTesterHelper)){
            return false;
        }
        EqualsTesterHelper a = (EqualsTesterHelper) obj;
        System.out.println("In equals, a.test: " + a.test );
        System.out.println("In equals, this.test: " + this.test );
        System.out.println("In equals, equals: " + (this.test  == a.test));
        return (a.test == this.test);
    }

}
```

Or is it better to add locking on both object in my Runnable:

```
 public void run() {
        while (true){
            modifyHelper(helper1, rand.nextInt(10));
            synchronized(helper1){
                synchronized(helper2){
                    helper1.equals(helper2);
                }
            }
            modifyHelper(helper2, rand.nextInt(10));
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I had a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636399/correctly-synchronizing-equals-in-java), however it seems the only answer is that you should ensure objects are not modified during the evaluation of equals (or hashcode) which does not hint to which solution would be better.

**Edit**: Actually I realized that my "synchronized" equals is flawed as I would still need to synchronize on the object passed in the method.

Comment: Why would one want to synchronize `equals` or `hashCode`? Do your implementations of these methods change the state of the object?

Comment: It depends.....

Comment: It's best to make `equals` and `hashCode` depend on immutable properties of the instance, for reasons other than multithreading. For example, if `hashCode` can change, you might not be able to find it in a `HashSet` afterwards.

Comment: @mike: The field can be changed by a concurrent thread while equals is evaluating a mutable field.

Comment: @kaqqao: Well the bound is 10 and there are 100 threads, from time to time they can be equal...

Comment: Then do your synchronization outside. The method that modifies the value and the one calling `equals` should then be sync'd. Not `equals` itself.

Comment: @AndyTurner: As much as I agree with you, there are cases where mutable objects implements equals, like ArrayList.

Comment: @asettouf and in that case, you should be using external synchronization, as stated in the Javadoc.

Comment: @mike, Whenever it is important to synchronize methods that modify an object, it is almost always just as important to synchronize methods that only examine the object.  We synchronize methods that update the object because we don't want one of them to operate on it when the other already has put it into a temporarily invalid state.  For the same reason, we don't want methods that inspect the object to see it in that invalid state.

Comment: @AndyTurner Can I know which part of the Javadoc you are referring to?

Comment: Why not just use `AtomicInteger`s to hold the values?

Comment: @BarrySW19 Because it's an example case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to synchronize `equals()`.

Suppose you have this code:

```
Foobar foobarA = ...;
Foobar foobarB = ...;
if (foobarA.equals(foobarB)) {
    doSomethingThatOnlyMakesSenseIfTheyAreEqual(...);
}
```

If there's other threads that potentially could alter the equality of the two objects, then adding `synchronized` to the `equals` method will *not* ensure that the objects are equal when `doSomething...()` gets called.

The reason is simple:  The other thread(s) could change the relationship *after* the `equals()` call returns `true`, but before or during the `doSomething...()` call.

If it needs synchronization, then you'd have to synchronize it like this:

```
Foobar foobarA = ...;
Foobar foobarB = ...;
Object lock = new Object();

synchronized(lock) {
    if (foobarA.equals(foobarB)) {
        doSomethingThatOnlyMakesSenseIfTheyAreEqual(...);
    }
}
```

And, of course, the code that modifies the objects also would have to be synchronized on the same `lock`.

Comment: You have a point there, though I would suppose that if your equals method is  used to test equality at a certain moment in a test, you might not need to "do something that make sense"

Comment: @asettouf How can you define "a certain moment" when there are multiple threads running with no synchronization?   Put it another way, What's the use of thread A knowing that the two objects _were_ equal, at some point in its past if it can never know whether they _are_ equal now?  And don't forget that unsynchronized thread do not necessarily see things happen in the same order.  What's the point in knowing that they _were_ equal at some point in thread A's past if there's no way to know if they ever were equal in some other thread's past?

Comment: Let's say you have an object, you create a second object from a HTTP request that should be equal to the first object, you have defined a timeout of 10 seconds, after that you check that both are equals. During this equals calls, if objects are not equals, at "10 seconds + delta t" you could have the object created and equals still returns true, although the timeout of 10 seconds was passed (fair enough it's obviously an edge case, as is my question)

Comment: also having `equals` synchronized can prevent modification errors (ie if your `equals` method checks whether some inner value is null and then if it isn't it operates on belief that value is not null other thread changing inner state to null can throw hard to debug `NullPointerException`)...